# How to set global font-family in Apache FOP?

Tags: java, apache, pdf, fonts, apache-fop

This is what I've used before:

```
 <fo:block font-family="Tahoma">Text</fo:block>
```

How can I specify that "Tahoma" is the font-family for the entire document?

I am looking for an equivalent of CSS's

```
body {
  font-family: "Tahoma";
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to set default font for whole document you can set it in fo:root. It should get inherited by every child-node without specified font-family.

```
<fo:root font-family="Tahoma">
    <!-- rest of document -->
</fo:root>
```

Comment: fo:root element does not have font-family property. See specification (http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xsl-20011015/slice6.html#fo_root)

Comment: Whilst it may not be in the spec, I can verify it works for me in Apache FOP

Comment: @Ryan for me with FOP 2.4 it doesn't.

Comment: Works for me with FOP 2.7

Answer (score 4):

you can use the node fo:wrapper to inherit properties to its content-childs

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4-portrait">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:wrapper font-size="10pt" font-family="Tahoma">
            <fo:block>
                Text <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block>
                Another text
            </fo:block>
        </fo:wrapper>
    </fo:flow>   
</fo:page-sequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <fonts>
    <referenced-fonts>
      <match font-family="Tahoma"/>
    </referenced-fonts>
  </fonts>
```

OR

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4-portrait">
  <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
    <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="Tahoma">
      Text <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    </fo:block>
  </fo:flow>   
</fo:page-sequence>
```

Comment: the first way doesn't seem to work and the second .. how is it different from what I've written in my question? (a local font-family) ?

Comment: Here is a link to original Apache's documentation of [FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/fonts.html) I've used it in my project's configs. It works pretty nice.

Comment: Note that I am embedding the font

Comment: The first doesn't set the default font; And what does the second snippet do according to you?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this the way it is done in CSS if you do not actually HAVE an element to match for your particular font.
If all you want is set a font for everything but some exception, setting it on <fo:root> then changing it when you need to should do the trick.
Whether the font is a default font or defined via your config file does not make a difference.

Edit:

The equivalent of

```
body {   font-family: "Tahoma"; }
```

would be

```
<xsl:template match="body">
    <fo:block font-family="Tahoma">
        Content
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: and I assume that `Content` is the body i.e. I have to place my entire document there?